# How to add application built-in services (menu bar commands) in Automator?

Tags: macos, automator

I am wondering whether it is possible to use built-in services (menu bar options) of specific applications in Automator.

For instance, I want to create a service to launch Google Chrome and open a new window (the effect of <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> when Chrome is active).

Is it possible?

Comment: Using a service to start Chrome seems a bit strange. Can you elaborate a bit more on the problem you are trying to solve, maybe there are better solutions than creating an Automator workflow.

Comment: Well, I don't think it's strange at all. The best thing about services is keyboard shortcuts. Beyond that, sometimes I need to keep a Chrome window open in full screen presentation mode and perform tasks in new windows. It's not cool to Command Tab to switch into a Chrome full screen window, Command N to launches a new full screen window, and Command Control F to exit full screen mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use AppleScript for that. In Automator, drag *Run AppleScript* to the right pane, and for the script, enter the following:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    make new window
    activate
end tell
```

The `activate` is optional, but it'll bring Chrome to the front.

Comment: Cool, it works. Thank you very much! Guess I really need to spend some time on applescripts. I've always been lazy about that.

Comment: Glad to help! AppleScript can be hard to learn since it's a little different to get things done if you know other programming languages, but it's fun after a while. Since you're new to Stack Exchange, did you know you can accept answers that worked for you? Just click the green checkmark next to their score :)

Comment: I happened to check that just one second ago ;)